# Python MNIST dataset using sklearn, select specific digits

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mnist

I’m training few models on MNIST dataset using Sklearn, how do I train the linear model using only two digits 4 and 9 (two classes) from the MNIST dataset?

- how to pick my `X_test,X_train, y_test,y_train`?

Comment: Thanks for answering, what if I had to choose only 4?

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you only want to use the images of the digit 4 and 9.

**You need indexing like `X[np.logical_or(y == 4, y == 9)]`:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

digits = load_digits()

X = digits.data
y = digits.target

#Select only the digit 4 and 9 images
X = X[np.logical_or(y == 4, y == 9)]
y = y[np.logical_or(y == 4, y == 9)]

# verify selection
np.unique(y)
#array([4, 9])

# Now split them
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, train_size=200, test_size=100)
```

---

To use only the digit 4:

```
X = digits.data
y = digits.target

#Select only the digit 4 and 9 images
X = X[y == 4]
y = y[y == 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to train model with only 4?